# Eclipse Launched Maven project not using classes in the \target folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, launcher

I have a project which I am converting from plain Java to Maven.

I used the `"Configure -> Convert to Maven Project"` option in eclipse.

I removed all jars in the classpath and referenced them in my POM file and built the project

My new classes are built in `project/target` but when I launch from eclipse, (using the original launcher) , the old classes are in `project\bin` folder are used.

How do I reconfigure this to use the correct classes ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the configuration for output files in eclipse has not change.
Try to change the output of generated files in eclipse manually:

1. Right click in project -> Properties.
2. Select "Java build path" and tab "Sources".
3. At bottom you have a field named "Default output folder". Change it for: `<your-project>/target/classes`

For example:

[image]
Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks , that setting is already pointing at the  /target/classes folder ...so the problem is something else

Comment: I usually import the projects "as maven project" to eclipse instead of convert it to maven project. Maybe you can try to:
1. Delete the project from your workspace (be carefull, not phisically)
2. Delete all generared files in project directory, specially .classpath, .project and .settings folder. 3. In eclipse, import project as maven project and choose your pom.xml